# Illustrator - How to align different sections of text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am creating a coffee shop menu. How can I achieve proper alignment? I have tried using the Tab key but this doesn't create uniformity. Rough example below.

I have spent soo much time trying to work this out, any help would be massively appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator has a tabs control panel which can be opened using *Window > Type > Tabs*

Select your text, and enable the Tabs panel, and set up the tabs you require

[image]